# WSO2 dashboard gadget customization

Tags: wso2, dashboard

I'm using WSO2 DAS product and I'm using a deafult gadget provided by WS02 product; when the gadget receives data it's all correct but the legend of data is moved on the right cutting words and It's not so good to visualize.
Attachment included.

Regards.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPF4g.png)

Comment: please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update your question with the required details

Answer (score 0):

If your data set has lengthy characters, you can increase right padding of the chart. When you generate a gadget, a directory for the gadget is created inside following directory

```
<DAS-PACK-HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal/store/carbon.super/fs/gadget/
```

Inside there go js directory and open the JS generated for bar chart. This file contains the chart drawing logic, here VizGrammar [1][2] has been used as the charting library and configuration for that is generated inside buildChartConfig() function. There add following line to reconfigure the padding, here i have incrased right padding as 90.

```
conf.padding = {"top": 10, "left": 50, "bottom": 40, "right": 90}
```

[1] http://wso2.github.io/VizGrammar/samples/

[2] https://github.com/wso2/VizGrammar